# Is there a better technology than Apacher River (Jini) for Remote Procedure Calls?

Tags: java, websocket, distributed-computing, jini

I am planning to do a simple Remote Procedure Call (RPM) over the web and I am currently using WebSockets. I was wondering if Jini is better than WebSockets or if there is a newer API or framework for Java to do RPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSockets and Jini are the *main* ones of note, both have their pluses and minuses. I'd say WebSockets is great just for the sheer amount of examples and documentation lying about. Jini is a lot different than WebSockets - so if anything the overheard of learning how to use it may not be worth it; that is up to you to evaluate, I spose.

Comment: I found a useful presentation [Remoting Retrospective - Harold Carr](http://haroldcarr.net/computerScience/presentations/2012-10-02-JavaOne-BOF7007-Harold-Carr-REMOTING-RETROSPECTIVE.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use WebSockets directly because older browsers and/or corporate firewalls may have issues with it.  [SocksJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client)
is a respected wrapper that will gracefully degrade to another transport mechanism if required while still allowing you to work with a WebSockets type of API.

The client side is generally written in JavaScript but they have a number of servers written including two in Java: [Vert.x](https://github.com/vert-x/vert.x) and [Netty](https://github.com/cgbystrom/sockjs-netty).  It looks like the Vert.x implementation is a little more mature at this point in time.